# allow only frontend domain to access apis in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have apis setup behind nginx. i want only my frontend domain for example `https://myfrontend.com` to access the apis

i have tried using check `$host` but thats the same as `server_name`

```bash
/api {
    # how to do i allow only myfrontend.com to access it?
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
}
```

help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

solved for me.

```
location / {
    if ($http_origin != "https://myfrontend.com") {
        return 403;
    }
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```